# How to fix captured image rotation for CameraX?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I try to use new CameraX api and I got this error: When I capture the image this image stored with wrong rotation. For example I capture in portrait orientation but result image in landscape orientation.

There is my code:

```
private fun startCamera() {
    val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setTargetResolution(Size(textureView.width, textureView.height))
        setTargetRotation(textureView.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setCaptureMode(CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
        setTargetAspectRatio(RATIO_4_3)
        setTargetRotation(textureView.display.rotation)
    }.build()
    imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)

    val preview = Preview(previewConfig)
    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { previewOutput ->
        removeView(textureView)
        addViewMatchParent(textureView, position = 0)
        textureView.surfaceTexture = previewOutput.surfaceTexture
        textureView.updateTransformForCameraFinderView()
    }
    (context as? LifecycleOwner)?.let { lifecycleOwner ->
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, preview, imageCapture)
    }
}

private fun capturePhoto() {
    tempImageFile = generateTmpFile(false)
    val executor = Executor { it.run() }
    imageCapture.takePicture(tempImageFile!!, executor, object : OnImageSavedListener {
        override fun onError(error: ImageCaptureError, message: String, exc: Throwable?) {
            exc?.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onImageSaved(photoFile: File) {
            post {
                // load image into ImageView by Glide
                showCapturedPhotoPreview(photoFile)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Please give me advise how can I fix it?

P.S. I tried to find solution so don't copy-paste first looking like something similar)

**Update:** I tried to do my CameraView like in [this sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic) but in their case it works, in my - no)

Comment: Since there are many similar topics here, but you say you don't want people to give you the generic solutions, it might be worth mentioning what else you've tried and how it failed in your case.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yes, thank you for your advise, added one link to sample project. The cameraX is still in alpha so there are very rare questions and answers(

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setCaptureMode(CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
        setTargetAspectRatio(RATIO_4_3)
        // play with this line!
        setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
        setTargetRotation(textureView.display.rotation)
    }.build()
```

I select line that fixes my problem again:

```
setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
```

Comment: not working for me with setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0). any idea?